# Android Доступ к SharedPreferences в Service

Tags: android, service, android-preferences

Во время использования SharedPreferences наткнулся на проблему с доступом к записанным данным.

Имеется класс MainActivity, в котором при помощи пользовательского интерфейса изменяются некоторые значения, после применения которых происходит запись в некий SharedPreferences. Сам MainActivity совершенно спокойно относится к таким динамическим изменениям внутри себя, т.е. после каждого commit() из SharedPreferences извлекается всегда новое значение. К данному MainActivity прилагается MyService, который может быть вызван нажатием кнопки.

При первом вызове startService, созданный MyService считывает в своём onCreate свежие данные из SharedPreferences. Однако в дальнейшем изменения данных SharedPreferences из тела MainActivity не приводят к ожидаемому изменению данных в MyService даже после остановки и повторного вызова startService().

Единственным возможным вариантом для обновления данных в MyService является перезапуск всего Application. После данной процедуры первый вызов startService вновь даст в onCreate MyService'а свежие данные.

**Код MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public SharedPreferences sPrefs;
    public static final String PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME = "PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME";
    public int prefs_audio_output_volume = MyService.DEFAULT_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME; //DEFAULTS = 75%
    Intent intentService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setMainContentView();
        intentService = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    }

    public void setMainContentView()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        //sPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_CATALOG_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        prefs_audio_output_volume = sPrefs.getInt(PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME, prefs_audio_output_select);  //DEFAULTS = 75%
        ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarAudioOutput)).setProgress(prefs_audio_output_volume);

        ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarAudioOutput)).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            sPrefsSaveInteger(seekBar.getProgress(), PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volume: "+sPrefs.getInt(PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME,prefs_audio_output_volume), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        }
        });
    }

    public void sPrefsSaveInteger(int input,String name)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor sPrefsEditor = sPrefs.edit();
        sPrefsEditor.putInt(name, input);
        sPrefsEditor.commit();
        //sPrefsEditor.apply();
    }

    public void click_Service(View v)
    {
        boolean working = isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class);
        if (!working) {
            startService(intentService);
        } else {
            stopService(intentService);
        }
    }
}
```

**Код MyService:**

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    public static final int DEFAULT_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME = 75;   //DEFAULTS = 75%
    public SharedPreferences sPrefs;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volume: "+sPrefs.getInt(MainActivity.PREFS_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME,DEFAULT_AUDIO_OUTPUT_VOLUME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода, были предприняты попытки использовать и getSharedPreferences, и .Apply().

Повторюсь, проблема заключается в том, что данные для MyService обновляются только во время первого вызова MyService после перезапуска всего приложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема успешно решилась изменением файла AndroidManifest.xml

Фрагмент с объявлением Service содержал в себе изменение имени процесса, который и влиял таким образом на работу SharedPreferences.

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":Any">
</service>
```

После присвоения данного значения всему Application, приложение начало корректно извлекать данные из SharedPreference.

```
 <application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:process=":Any">
 ...
```

Comment: может лучше удалить этот атрибут у сервиса?

Comment: В дальнейшем я так и поступил, однако названный выше вариант также является приемлемым для тех, кому данный параметр может оказаться необходимым.

Answer (score 2):

Все потому, что `onCreate()` у сервиса вызывается один раз, при первом его запуске, и не вызовется до того момента, как сервис будет убит. Когда вы делаете `startService()` каждый очередной раз вызывается не `onCreate()`, а `onStartCommand()`. Перенесите ваш код из `onCreate()` в `onStartCommand()`

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что после вызова `stopService(intent)` и повторного вызова `startService(intent)` `onCreate()` вызваемого сервиса будет пропущен?