# Activity, Service и Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-service, android-shared-preferences

Подскажите, я туплю или что - есть Активити и Сервис.
Они оба пишут/читают SharedPreferences. Но один читает то, что сохранил, а второй читает "пустоту". Активити читает из основного потока, сервис пишет из созданного треда. Но хранилище же одно. Как так может быть?

-------- дополнение - код ---------------

1. Есть сласс Config со статическими переменными и методами. В частности ест методы Save и Update. Оставлена одна переменная для примера,  атак их мого таких (корявость самого кода сохранени\восстановления конечно есть, но такое уж наследе)

   ```
       public class Config 
       {
           static public StorageInterface st = null;

           static public int[] redraw       = new int[100];    //--- необходимость обновить

           public static void save()
           {
           String redraw       = "";

           for (int i=10; i<=50; i+=10)
           {
                redraw       += ","+Config.redraw[i];
           }
           Config.st.setItem("redraw",   redraw);

           Config.st.setItem("act",   ""+Config.act);
           Config.st.setItem("locked",   ""+Config.locked);
           Config.st.setItem("screen_off",   ""+Config.screen_off);
           }

           public static void update()
           {

           String[] redraw      = Config.st.getItem("redraw",   ",0,0,0,0,0").split(",");

           for (int i=10; i<=50; i+=10)
           {
               Config.redraw[i]      = Integer.parseInt(redraw[i/10],  10);
           }

           }

       }
   ```

Сохрание и чтение (просто обертка по сути)

```
         public class StorageInterface {

                SharedPreferences sPref;
                Context activ;

                public StorageInterface(Context a)
                {
         //         Config.log("NEW CONTEXT = "+a);
                    activ = a;
                }

                public void link(Context a)
                {
                    activ = a;
                }


                //Play an audio file from the webpage
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void setItem(String item, String val)
                {
         //             sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        sPref = activ.getSharedPreferences("st", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Editor ed = sPref.edit();

                        ed.putString("st_"+item, val);

                      if (item.equals("redraw"))
                        Config.log("ST save: "+"st_"+item+" = "+val);
                        ed.commit();
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public String getItem(String item)
                {
                    return getItem(item, "");
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public String getItem(String item, String val)
                {
                        sPref = activ.getSharedPreferences("st", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        String tmp = sPref.getString("st_"+item, val);

                        if (item.equals("redraw"))
                        Config.log("ST read: "+"st_"+item+" = "+tmp);


                        return(  tmp );
                }
            }
```

В самом активити :

```
   public class webActivity extends Activity implements  
   MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, View.OnClickListener,    LockscreenUtils.OnLockStatusChangedListener, OnTouchListener/*, SensorEventListener*/ {
      ...

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (Config.st == null)
                Config.st = new StorageInterface(this);
            else
                Config.st.link(this);

     }

     //--- НУ и гдето в коде:

     Config.Update();

      //--- и далее доступ к самой переменной
      if (Config.redraw[i]==1)
       {
       }

   }
```

В сервисе как то так:

```
   public class LockscreenService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

       private Thread T   = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            Config.log("LSS Created");


        if (Config.st == null)
                Config.st = new StorageInterface(this);
            else
                Config.st.link(this);

        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

                    if (intent.hasExtra("act"))
                {
                    int act = intent.getIntExtra("act", 0);

                    if (act == 1)
                    {
                            T = new Thread( new updateMediaTask() );                                
                            if (T!=null)
                                T.start();
                    }

        }

     }
```

Ну и этот созданный поток pdateMediaTask  у себя в run  делает тоже

```
          Config.Update();
          ...
          Config.wedraw[i] = 1;
          ...
          Config.Save();
```

Бррр, пока написал сам мозг поломал... 
В общем суть такая - сервис по событию запускает поток, тот лезет на сервер, проверяет данные, если надо возводит флаги и све это сует в преференсез. Потом когда активити снова будет активно оно смотрит в эти преференсез и ,если надо, обновляет элементы..
И чето вот не обновляет...  Толи лыжи не едут, толи я....

Comment: нужно больше кода...

Comment: сейчас изобразим..  там просто все разбросано по разным местам, получится слишком много кода.... сейчас выжимку сделаю.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481567/177345 ?

Comment: Это про android:process=":Any"  ?  у меня такого нет вобще ни где...  Видимо что-то другое я  упустил.

Comment: В общем переделал вместо SharedPreferences на хранение в файлах - работает.